# how to implement this algorithm in python?

Tags: python, algorithm

This is some type of cartesian product that is spawned from an initial fixed length series of integers, generate additional series, using the rule dictated by the symbol that dictates the `n` number of additional series that must follow.

for example (`^` produces additional 1 series, `*` produces additional 3 series)

```
1 0^ 1* 1
```

generates

```
1 0 2 1
1 0 3 1
1 0 4 1 (we stop here because we have produced 3 additional series)

1 1 1* 1 (we have produced an additional series from the `^` symbol. still have the `*`)

1 1 2 1
1 1 3 1 
1 1 4 1
```

Another example, now with a larger length series and additional rule.

```
1 0^ 1* 0^ 1
```

generates

```
1 0 2 0 1
1 0 3 0 1
1 0 4 0 1

1 0^ 1* 1 1

1 0 2 1 1 
1 0 3 1 1 
1 0 4 1 1 

1 1 1* 1 1 

1 1 2 1 1 
1 1 3 1 1 
1 1 4 1 1
```

I was just bored and started writing a whole series of numbers like this on paper and was curious to know if there was already an algorithm or implementation which generates such sequence of series of integers. Note that there's new line between series that generates additional series to make it easier to understand.

Comment: It vaguely reminds me of a regular language specification, generating strings from it but with custom symbols you seem to have invented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for Cartesian products in general. Specifically, I would implement your algorithm in two separate steps:

1. Parse the input string (e.g. `"1 0^ 1* 0^ 1"`) into a list of lists of integers; and
2. Produce the product of the list of lists.

A relatively simple generator-based implementation, with a helper function for clarity, would look like:

```
def algorithm(input_):
    # Step 1
    instructions = []
    for s in input_.split():
        try:
            instructions.append([int(s)])
        except ValueError:
            instructions.append(list(values(s)))
    # Step 2
    for prod in itertools.product(*instructions):
        yield prod

def values(s):
    RULES = {'*': 4, '^': 2}
    n = int(s[:-1])
    for x in range(RULES[s[-1]]):
        yield n + x
```

For example:

```
>>> print("\n".join(" ".join(map(str, t)) for t in algorithm("1 0^ 1* 1")))
1 0 1 1
1 0 2 1
1 0 3 1
1 0 4 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 2 1
1 1 3 1
1 1 4 1
```

You will have to tinker with it to get the precise order (you appear to have an operator, rather than left-to-right, precedence) and formatting (e.g. spaces between groups) you're looking for.

Comment: yeah essential `1 0 1 1 ` equals `list(1,0,1,1)`. `itertools` seems like to do the job