# How do I iterate through a list to print each variable in the list?

Tags: python, list, printing, iteration

If i have this as my code:

```
import sys
from sys import argv
if len(sys.argv) == 7:
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g = argv
    c_list = c.split(',')
    d_list = d.split(',')
    if len(c_list) == len(d_list):
        print b
    elif len(d_list) == len(c_list):
        print b
    else:
        sys.exit()
    for c in c_list:
        if len(c_list) == len(d_list):
            print c
        else:
            sys.exit()
    for d in d_list:
        if len(d_list) == len(c_list):
            print d
        else:
            sys.exit()
    print e
    print f
    print g

else:
    a,b,c,d,e,f = argv
    c_list = c.split(',')
    d_list = d.split(',')
    if len(c_list) == len(d_list):
        print b
    elif len(d_list) == len(c_list):
        print b
    else:
        sys.exit() 
    for c in c_list:
        if len(c_list) == len(d_list):
            print c
        else:
            sys.exit()
    for d in d_list:
        if len(d_list) == len(c_list):
            print d
        else:
            sys.exit()
    print e
    print f
```

It allows me to pass the following to argv:

```
a b c,c1,c2 d,d1,d2 e f g
```

and the other code I have leads to this list printing as

```
    a 
    b 
    c
    c1
    c2
    d
    d1
    d2
    e
    f
    g
```

However, I want it to print the following:

```
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e 
    f
    g
    a
    b
    c1
    d1
    e
    f
    g
```

and so on and so forth. How would I do this? If this seems super basic, I apologize. As a high school freshman, I am still trying to figure out how the complex world of coding works.

Comment: I do not understand the logic behind your desired output. How do you get that? How exactly do you want it organized? You need to show us your code that does the printing; we can't possibly know what the error is otherwise.

Comment: This is not valid Python syntax. What is this `a b c d e f g = argv`? Where is your user input coming from?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense  I went ahead and added my whole code

Comment: @user3861531 it's still not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23709681/3001761) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/533905/3001761).

Comment: @jonrsharpe instead of it printing the different c values one after another, I wanted it to print the whole list again, with each print going through each additional c value.

Comment: @user3861531 then `itertools.product` is probably what you want - check the links I just added.

Comment: If you want to iterate through `c` and `d` in pairs, you may want to `zip`, too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe and how would that work?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I figured out how to zip the lists (c and d lists) but how do i write a print function that prints the rest of the list, with the zipped pairs mixed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I think you want something like this:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = [3, 4, 5]
>>> d = [6, 7, 8]
>>> for cx, dx in zip(c, d):
        for item in (a, b, cx, dx):
            print(item)
        print("---")


1
2
3
6
---
1
2
4
7
---
1
2
5
8
---
```